# Garbage Appended to Output When Reading Values from a File

Tags: c++, file-io, stream

I'm new to C++ file io, so the other day I decided to write a small program that simply reads a UTF-8 encoded string and a paired float from a binary file. The pattern is string-float with no extra data or spacing between pairs. **EDIT** I've revised the code based on several answers. However, the output remains the same ("The RoommateAp 0");

```
string readString (ifstream* file)
{
    //Get the length of the upcoming string
    uint16_t stringSize = 0;
    file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stringSize), sizeof(char) * 2);

    //Now that we know how long buffer should be, initialize it
    char* buffer = new char[stringSize + 1];
    buffer[stringSize] = '\0';

    //Read in a number of chars equal to stringSize
    file->read(buffer, stringSize);
    //Build a string out of the data
    string result = buffer;

    delete[] buffer;
    return result;
}

float readFloat (ifstream* file)
{
    float buffer = 0;
    file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(float));
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    //Create new file that's open for reading
    ifstream file("movies.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);
    //Make sure the file is open before starting to read
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            cout << readString(&file) << endl;
            cout << readFloat(&file)  << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }
}
```

And a sample of data from the file (spaces for readability):

```
000C 54686520526F6F6D6D617465 41700000
```

As one can see, the first two bytes are the length of the string (12 in this case), followed by twelve characters (which spell "The Roommate"), and the final four bytes are a float.

When I run this code, the only thing that happens is that the terminal hangs and I have to close it manually. I think it may be because I am reading past the end of the file, but I have no idea why this would happen. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is that the data as would be seen in a *hex* editor?  Or a *text* editor?

Comment: That is the data as would be seen in a hex editor.

Comment: I hope you're on a big-endian machine.  Because if you're on a little-endian machine, that's not 12, it's 3072.

Comment: I'm on an Intel machine, so little-endian. However, printing out the value of stringSize verifies that it's value is 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two issues. First, the line:

```
file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(stringSize), sizeof(char) * 2);
```

Probably should take the address of `stringSize`:

```
file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stringSize), sizeof(stringSize));
```

Second, the line:

```
char* buffer = new char[stringSize];
```

Doesn't allocate enough memory, since it doesn't take the `NUL` terminator into account. That code should do something like:

```
//Now that we know how long buffer should be, initialize it
char* buffer = new char[stringSize + 1];
//Read in a number of chars equal to stringSize
file->read(buffer, stringSize);
buffer[stringSize] = '\0';
```

Finally, the line:

```
return static_cast<string>(buffer);
```

Fails to `delete[]` the buffer after instantiating a `string` from it, which will cause a memory leak.

Also note that `std::string`'s UTF-8 support is quite poor out of the box. Fortunately, there are [solutions](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: That was a silly mistake. I was changing code around trying different things, and I accidentally left out the &. Output is now **The RoommateAp 0** (with a newline between RoommateAp and 0.

Comment: Damn - I missed the static_cast. May be worth mentioning that the std::string class has a method which gives the pointer to the buffer (similar to c_str but without a separate buffer or null terminating - I forget the spelling). Also, the resize method is important in this context, to ensure that both the string size and its underlying buffer are big enough.

Comment: You *can* static_cast a char* to a string, because std::string has a constructor that takes a char*.(but he does still need to delete the pointer)

Comment: Buffer is actually an array of chars, and isn't that what a string is as well?

Comment: @PigBen, you're absolutely right, apparently that even works if the constructor is `explicit`. Answer updated accordingly, thanks :)

Comment: However, there is still a serious problem with the conversion, which I didn't notice at first.  The char array is not null-terminated.  6502 presented the solution to this problem.

Comment: Yup, just saw it also. +1 to him.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few serious problems:

1. `file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(stringSize), sizeof(char) * 2);`

   in this part you are casting the **current value** of `stringSize` into
    a pointer. Your idea was most probably instead to pass the address of
    the `stringSize` variable.
2. `char* buffer = new char[stringSize];`

   This allocates an array of chars, but no one is going to free it. Use
   `std::vector<char> buffer(stringSize);` instead so that the memory
   management will be done correctly for you.
   To get the address of the buffer you can use `&buffer[0]`.
3. `return static_cast<string>(buffer);`

   What you probably want is the string constructor that accepts
   pointers to first and one-past-last characters. In other words:
   `return std::string(&buffer[0], &buffer[0]+stringSize);`

Answer (score 0):

You cast to a character array. Does the string size number in the file include space for the null character? If not, you might be running off the end of a character array and looping forever on the cout write.

Comment: Possibly... however, looking at the data, however, it doesn't appear that there are any null characters at the end of the strings. If you look at the first post, the string length is specified as 000C (12), and the string data is 12 bytes long. It's readable representation ("The Roommate") is 12 characters long, so I don't think there's any nulls there.

Comment: You read a size from the file and then populate a buffer of that size. Then you cast the buffer to a string and return it. It's picked up by the stream operator at that point; if the buffer didn't get populated with a null character, the stream operator might not know when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code.

You state that the size of the string is specified by 4 bytes, that means you should use a uint32_t not a uint16_t.

You do not free the memory used when you allocate the string buffer.

```
string readString(std::ifstream* file)
{
    // Get the length of the upcoming string.
    // The length of the string is specified with 4 bytes: use uint32_t, not uint16_t
    uint32_t stringSize = 0;    
    file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stringSize), sizeof(uint32_t));

    // Now that we know how long buffer should be, initialize it
    char* buffer = new char[stringSize + 1];
    buffer[stringSize] = '\0'; // null terminate the string

    //Read in a number of chars equal to stringSize
    file->read(buffer, stringSize);
    string result = buffer;

    delete[] buffer;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Woops, that's a mistake on my part. I meant to say the first **two** bytes. Also, I left out delete[] for the sake of brevity.